# How to set Fiddler2 prefered Text Editor for Rules?

Tags: settings, fiddler

I've read the FAQ and set my registry key to use a custom text editor... and it works for the "view in notepad" button on the header panels. But when I try to edit rules (via menu `Rules` > `Customize rules`) I still get notepad.

Do I need to edit some reg key not mentioned in the FAQ? or is this a bug?

Comment: <s>it sure makes for weird reading if i'm looking at a list that is not filtered by tags...</s> ok, read the linked meta question and understood your point. removed the "tag:" prefix.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Fiddler v5**: `Tools -> Options -> Tools -> Text Editor`

**For older versions** this might be an option:

`Tools` > `Fiddler Options...` > `Extensions` > `Editor`.

Comment: awesome! thanks. don't know how i missed that one. the FAQ could mention it for the other short sighted out there before mentioning the registry keys :)

Comment: FWIW, your best bet may be to install the FiddlerScript Editor, which both configures itself, and include syntax-highlighting and intellisense.

Comment: @EricLaw-MSFT- thanks will try that... but gvim is so much nicer :)

Comment: I switched it to use Notepad++.

Comment: Fiddler v5: `Tools->Options->Tools->Text Editor`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it has changed in the latest version of Fiddler.  The setting can now be found by going to:

```
Tools > Telerik Fiddler Options... > Tools > Text Editor.
```

Answer (score 0):

for Progress Telerik Fiddler Web Debugger
v5.0.20182.28034 for .NET 4.6.1
Built: Wednesday, June 27, 2018

`Tools > Tools > Text Editor`